# Establishing one to one relations with Entity Framework 7

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, one-to-one

Having the following parent class:

```
[Table("smart_recharge_registro")]
    public class SmartRechargeRegistro
    {
        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }    
        public SmartRechargeRequest request { get; set; }
        public SmartRechargeProceso proceso { get; set; }
        public SmartRechargeResponse response { get; set; }
    }
```

Which in turn references the following child classes:

```
[Table("smart_recharge_request")]
    public class SmartRechargeRequest

    {                       
        public String nombreDeUsuario { get; set; }
  
        public String passwordDeUsuario { get; set; }

        public String msisdnSuscriptor { get; set; }         
       
    }
```

and:

```
[Table("smart_recharge_proceso")]
    public class SmartRechargeProceso
    {
        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }    
    
        public String carrierId { get; set; }
        public String cliente { get; set; }
        public String network { get; set; }        
           
    }
```

and lastly:

```
[Table("smart_recharge_response")]
    public class SmartRechargeResponse
    {     
        public Boolean responseSuccess { get; set; }
        public int responseCode { get; set; }
        public String? responseDetails { get; set; }    
    
}
```

The Add-Migration and Update-Database command execute without problems. However, when I try to save

```
  await _repository.RegistroColeccion.AddAsync(registro);
  await _repositorio.SaveChangesAsync();
```

I get the following error:

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: Could not save changes. Please configure your entity type accordingly.

> ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Cannot add
> or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
> (`beservicebroker_dev`.`registro_eventos_srdotnet`, CONSTRAINT
> `FK_registro_eventos_srdotnet_SmartRechargeProceso_procesoid` FOREIGN
> KEY (`procesoid`) REFERENCES `smartrechargeproceso` (`id`) O)

To solve the problem, I tried to create one-to-one relationships following [this tutorial](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<SmartRechargeRegistro>()
                .HasOne(s => s.request)
                .WithOne(r => r.SmartRechargeRegistro)
                .HasForeignKey<SmartRechargeRequest>(r => r.id);

            modelBuilder.Entity<SmartRechargeRegistro>()
                .HasOne(s => s.proceso)
                .WithOne(p => p.SmartRechargeRegistro)
                .HasForeignKey<SmartRechargeProceso>(p => p.id);

            modelBuilder.Entity<SmartRechargeRegistro>()
                .HasOne(s => s.response)
                .WithOne(r => r.SmartRechargeRegistro)
                .HasForeignKey<SmartRechargeResponse>(r => r.id);
```

Inside SmartRechargeRequest, SmartRechargeProceso and SmartRechargeResponse, added the following:

```
 [JsonIgnore]
public SmartRechargeRegistro SmartRechargeRegistro { get; set; }
```

Also added inside SmartRechargeRequest and SmartRechargeResponse an id

```
 [Key]
 public int id { get; set; }
```

I'm still unable to test the endpoint because the SmartRechargeRequest and SmartRechargeResponse are completely disfigured in the swagger (even if the [JsonIgnore] or  [IgnoreDataMember] annotations are set) due to the presence of that SmartRechargeRegistro object.

I'm pretty sure my solution is misguided and I'm getting the process completely wrong.

What would be the proper way to map one-to-one relationships for this case? Any help will be appreciated.

Please note that in reality, these classes are huge (dozens of properties), so it's not possible to merge all of them on a single table.